# Accessing User Entity From Form Type in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, multi-tenant

I'm trying to build multi-tenancy support in Symfony, doing this I created a `group_id` column in my User, on top of that, all entities also have this same column. That way users only have access to their group's data.

I've managed to cut through this whole thing like butter with data access and display, but then came the challenge of `EntityTypes` for the Symfony Forms.

The question is basically, how do I make the `EntityType` display only the data that that particular group has inputted. Sorting it by the `group_id` that both the user and contact has. Whats the best way to maybe pass this in so the user only has access to their data?

```
<?php 

namespace ContactBundle\Form; 

use ContactBundle\Entity\Contact; 
use ContactBundle\Entity\Organization;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface; 
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType; 
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType; 

class ContactType extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder 
        ->add('first_name', TextType::Class, [
            'attr' => ['class'=>'u-full-width'],
            'label' => 'First Name',])
        ->add('last_name', TextType::Class, [
            'attr' => ['class'=>'u-full-width'],
            'label'=>'Last Name',
        ])
        ->add('email', TextType::Class, [
            'attr' => ['class'=>'u-full-width'],
            'label'=>'Email Address'
        ])
        ->add('organization_id', EntityType::Class, [
            'attr' => ['class'=>'u-full-width'],
            'required' => false,
            'class'=>'ContactBundle:Organization',
            'choice_label'=>'name',
            'choice_value'=>'id',
            'label'=>'Organization'
        ])
        ->add('phone', TextType::Class, [
            'attr' => ['class'=>'u-full-width'],
            'label'=>'Phone',
        ])
        ->add('role', TextType::Class, [
            'attr' => ['class'=>'u-full-width'],
            'label'=>'Role',
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label'=>'Submit', 
            'attr' => [
                'class'=>'button-primary',
                'style'=>'margin-top:30px;',]]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class'=>Contact::class,]);
    }
}
?>
```

It is worth noting that I am using `FOSUserBundle`.

Comment: Write your own queries, docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Comment: @JimL - There's still the issue of passing in the group_id to the query.

Comment: I added an answer that further explains it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

So what I ended up doing was getting rid of the whole idea of using a EntityType on the form side.
I then called the data from the controller and passed it in as an option.
Like so:

```
$contactManager = $this->get('contact.contact_manager');
$contact = new Contact($contactManager->nextId($group = $this->getUser()->getGroupId()), $group);
$form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact, ['organizations' => $this->get('contact.organization_manager')->findDataCollection($this->getUser()->getGroupId())]);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Turned my EntityType into a choice type and passed the array of organizations into the 'choices' field as an option. Kept everything else the same like so:

```
    ->add('organization_id', ChoiceType::Class, [
        'attr' => ['class'=>'u-full-width'],
        'required' => false,
        'choices'=> $options['organizations'],
        'choice_label'=>'name',
        'choice_value'=>'id',
        'label'=>'Organization'
    ])
```

Then, of course, set it within the options so it can expect a variable.

```
$resolver->setDefaults(['data_class'=>Contact::class, 'organizations' => null]);
```

I appreciate all of the help and ideas!! :)

Answer (score 5):

In Symfony it's very easy to inject whatever you need where you need it.

```
// ...
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('organization_id', EntityType::Class, [
                'attr' => ['class'=>'u-full-width'],
                'required' => false,
                'class'=>'ContactBundle:Organization',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.group', '?0')
                        ->setParameters([$this->user->getGroup()]);
                },
                'choice_label'=>'name',
                'choice_value'=>'id',
                'label'=>'Organization'
            ])
            // ...
```

---

If you are not using autowire and autoconfigure (Symfony 3.3+), register your form as a service manually and tag it with form.type:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    AppBundle\Form\ContactType:
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
        tags: [form.type]
```

---

Related reads

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html#define-your-form-as-a-service

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Comment: Seems to not like that. Its throwing an exception 
    "Type error: Argument 1 passed to 
    ContactBundle\Form\ContactType::ContactBundle\Form\{closure}() 
    must be an instance of ContactBundle\Form\EntityRepository, 
    instance of ContactBundle\Repository\OrganizationRepository given". Seems it wants that repository but its getting overridden by whats in the "class" option?

Comment: Also, directly calling the user object from the form doesn't return anything. I don't think its available in this scope.

Comment: Ah, yes the query builder will give you the repository belonging to the entity in question (ContactBundle:Organization -> OrganizationRepository). Regarding the user not being available I just tried running similar code in a simple form in Symfony 3.3 and `$this->user` was available inside the closure for the query builder. You could make it explicitly use it by adding `'query_builder' => function (OrganizationRepository $repo) use ($user) {` but I'm honestly a bit lost as to why I don't need to

Comment: Would there be a way to use an entity manager that I had registered as a service in place of the OrganizationRepository? So I can do something like ` $this->get('contact.organization_manager') ` 1 instead? I'm running Symfony V 3.3.13. Check out ` https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder `.Is it doing this because its a form for contacts but I'm using the EntityType / Query Builder for an Organization?

Comment: You could use the manager and fetch the choices manually instead of using the query builder (though I would inject it instead of injecting the entire container), but I'm a bit lost. In this form field you add a field for the Organization entity, to me it sounds like you do want to use the organization repository. In order to help further it would be helpful to know what exactly this form field should allow you to select (which entity)

Answer (score 0):

In controller when creating form

```
$form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact, ['group_id' => $groupId]);
```

In form configureOptions method

```
$resolver->setDefaults(['data_class'=>Contact::class, 'group_id' => null]);
```

In form buildForm you can get group_id by

```
$options['group_id']
```

Comment: This seems like a step closer! But then comes the challenge of it accepting it within the query_builder attribute for the entity type. Doesn't seem to want to take it in. Is the query builder attribute and the required class attribute conflicting?

Comment: I'm gonna try calling it from the controller and passing it in as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in few different ways, one was to use combination of JavaScript and EntityType.

Basically just load all the entities and hide unwanted entities with JS depending on the previous list's selection. You can use data attribute to specify things needed to make that work.